# Can I create an instance for a static object?

Tags: c#, static

I am  following an online tutorial to learn how to write a serial communicator.

I am using VS2019 and .Net 5.0, which is different from the environment used in the tutorial.

To use the SerialPort tool, I try to create :

```
        static SerialPort serialPort1;
```

as in the code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace SerialPortCommunication {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {

        static SerialPort serialPort1;
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            string[] ports = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(ports);
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.Count > 0 ? 0 : -1;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (button1.Text == "Open Port") {
                serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
                serialPort1.Open();
                button1.Text = "Close Port";
            }
            else {
                serialPort1.Close();
                button1.Text = "Open Port";

            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

When I executed it , I encountered the System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

But after I changed it to

```
static SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort();
```

the VS doesn't show the Exception anymore.

My quesition is :

I have been told that we don't need and we can not create an instance for a static object, but in this case why do I need to create one instance to initialize the serialPort1?

I am confused...

As a beginner, I may have some unclear concepts. Could you provide me with some guidance or recommend some resources for me to study?

Comment: You can't create instances of static classes. `SerialPort` is not a static class. `serialPort1` is a static field.

Comment: And BTW: as C# is case-sensitive, you have to write `static` instead of `Static`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I correct it right away, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct: you can't create instances of static classes.

For example:

```cs
public static class Bob
{
    public void Test() => Console.WriteLine("hello");
}

var bob = new Bob(); // this won't compile
Bob.Test(); // this will because you're calling a static method
```

[`SerialPort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) is not a `static` class:

```cs
public class SerialPort : System.ComponentModel.Component
```

What you have is a `static` [field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields):

```cs
static SerialPort serialPort1;
```

And you're assigning an instance of `SerialPort` to it:

```cs
serialPort1 = new SerialPort();
```

The only difference is that you're doing this at the same time as declaring the field:

```cs
static SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort();
```

In short: you're not creating an instance of a static class, you're instantiating a static field with an instance of the non-static class `SerialPort`.

P.S. Please also note the difference between [fields and properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property) if you're unaware of these concepts.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it was very helpful in clarifying my understanding and now I know where I was mistaken!

Answer (score 0):

SerialPort is a component from System.IO.Ports and is not a static class.
you can define a serial port in csharp like this:

```
private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort serialPortRKE;
```

then you should set some settings like baudrate or PortName or ...

```
serialPortRKE.PortName = "COM3";
serialPortRKE.BaudRate = 9600;
serialPortRKE.DataBits = 8;
serialPortRKE.Handshake = Handshake.None;
serialPortRKE.Parity = Parity.Odd;
```

then based on your projects you can use DataReceived event or ...

```
this.serialPortRKE.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.serialPortRKE_DataReceived);
```

I think the CodeProject tutorial is very good:
[Serial Comms in C# for Beginners](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678025/Serial-Comms-in-Csharp-for-Beginners)